# Does “些” Work As A Suffix (Ever) In Mandarin Similar To “们”?

Tags: mandarin, usage, topolect

## [些](http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/2125.html)

> xiē
>
> 【名】
>
> [方言]：们〖-s〗——表示复数的词缀。如:婆娘些；娃儿些；老师些

Although marked as dialect (read: topolect), I'm curious to know if this usage is ever *acceptable* or *found* in MSM (Modern Standard Mandarin).

Comment: Yes, I checked this with my classmate who is from Sichuang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's only for some dialects in somewhere SiChuan.

> 在表示某类人时，成都人还爱用“些”作词尾，并将其读作[?i44]，音同“西”。例如：老师些，学生些，家长些，娃娃些，娃儿些，大人些，伙子些，姑娘儿些，女娃子些，男娃子些，儿娃子些，大娃娃些，小娃娃些，男人些，婆娘些，老头儿些，婆婆些，孃孃些，姆姆些，演员些，导演些，干部些，代表些，警察些，军官些，兵兵儿些，队员些，运动员些，贼娃子些，歹徒些，等等。

ref : http://www.ct17.com/bbs1/dispbbs.asp?boardid=1&Id=307&page=6